# how do I begin with ProTeXt?

Tags: protext

last night i first downloaded the ProTeXt distribution from http://in.httpd.co/mirrors/ctan/systems/windows/protext/

from this link, i got the 24june, 2014 release, and my installation is also complete. Now how do i begin with a documentation. it says "LaTexMng", what is it? and what accessory files do i needto begin?
regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Regarding your question about "LaTeXMng": it's a separate program that is meant to simplify the process of writing LaTeX documents. From the [README](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/systems/win32/latexmng/README) file: "LaTexMng is [an] easy to use product of integrated development environment software for Windows. This application integrates all the tools needed [for] the creation of LaTeX documents."

Comment: ProTeXt should give you what you need to create and compile LaTeX documents.  As to *how* to write or 'code' a document, a good starting place is [The not so Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/) (available in several different languages; download one of the PDFs to read).  There are also other questions on this site about starting out in the world of TeX / LaTeX / ConTeXt.

Comment: ProTeXt is a wrapper around MiKTeX and various additional tools. AS such, you can use it in much the same way as any other TeX system. I don't know the LaTeXMng editor, but we do have a [long list of IDEs for (La)TeX work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere on your disk, you create a new text file, for example `begin.txt`, and put this in it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

This is how I've begun with Latex.

\end{document}
```

Now you rename that file to `begin.tex`, and `Open` it.  With my last proTeXt installation that fired up TeXStudio on that document, I needed only press `F1`, and a pdf was created.

Next you decide what you want to achieve with LaTeX, and look for likely examples online, and in books, and you figure out the LaTeX commands as you go along.  It takes some dedication, but soon you realise how amenable LaTeX is.

I find a lot of the power and freedom of creating documents in LaTeX comes from using my preferred text editor, gVim in my case.  Also, as I'm working on an old netbook, I'm avoiding opening a resource heavy WYSIWYG word-processor program.